# Can i make the Alt Text field required in Kentico's Insert image or media dialog?

Tags: kentico

For the Editable Image web part, I know this can be done, but is it possible here? I've not been able to find the source code for the control.

Answer (score 5):

You can try to add something like

```cs
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtAlt.Text))
{
    errorMessage += " " + GetString("CustomErrorMessage");
}
```

into `Validate()` method in `CMSModules_Content_Controls_Dialogs_Properties_HTMLMediaProperties` somewhere into `case MediaTypeEnum.Image:` case.

Comment: Thanks. I see the case statements and i'll add to that.

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks for the help!